# Run command with exec() - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, exec

I have this file named 'localproxy' that I want to run.

File is in the same folder as my node script (conn_script.js)

[image]

If I try to run it with exac() function it throws me error:

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

And it works perfectly when I just paste the command in terminal, like this:

```
./localproxy -t some_long_string -r eu-central-1 -d localhost:22
```

This is the code:

```
exec('./localproxy -t some_long_string -r eu-central-1 -d localhost:22', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
 console.log(error)
})
```

I tried `execFile()`, I tried `'"./localproxy" -t some_long_string -r eu-central-1 -d localhost:22'`, and still nothing.

Can anyone explain and please help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is this file exactly? It looks like either a script or a Linux binary, and it seems you are testing it in either a Linux shell or a Git bash (in the latter case it can't be a binary). But your node.js seems to run in Windows and use the default `cmd.exe` as shell, hence the error (try running your command in cmd and you will get the same error).

Comment: Please describe in your question what environments you have - how/where you are running the command (what "terminal" are you referring to exactly?), how/where you are running your node.js application, and what type of file `localproxy` is exactly.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `localproxy`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am running it on Windows, and it is designed for Linux
I run it from VS Code terminal, and I get the same error in cmd also

Is there any way to run it on Windows?

Comment: Use the Windows path separator in the command name instead of the POSIX path separator.  That is, instead of `./localproxy` use `.\\localproxy`.  (The Windows separator is a single backslash, but the backslash has special meaning in a string so to end up with a single backslash you have to write `\\\`.)